# Why can't I get PHP to show me a single json element

Tags: php, json

Man this JSON thing is chewing away at my day.  Is it suppose to be this difficult?  Probably not.  Ok, so I am receiving a URL with a json data set in it.

It looks like this:

```
jsonval={%22Fname%22:+%22kjhjhkjhk%22,+%22Lname%22:+%22ghghfhg%22,+%22conf[]%22:+[%22ConfB%22,+%22ConfA2%22],+%22quote%22:+%22meat%22,+%22education%22:+%22person%22,+%22edu%22:+%22welding%22,+%22Fname2%22:+%22%22,+%22Lname2%22:+%22%22,+%22gender%22:+%22B2%22,+%22quote2%22:+%22Enter+your+meal+preference%22,+%22education2%22:+%22person2%22,+%22edu2%22:+%22weld2%22,+%22jsonval%22:+%22%22}
```

And when I run json_decode in PHP on it, it looks like this:

```
object(stdClass)#1 (13) { ["Fname"]=> string(9) "kjhjhkjhk" ["Lname"]=> string(7) "ghghfhg" ["conf[]"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(5) "ConfB" [1]=> string(6) "ConfA2" } ["quote"]=> string(4) "meat" ["education"]=> string(6) "person" ["edu"]=> string(7) "welding" ["Fname2"]=> string(0) "" ["Lname2"]=> string(0) "" ["gender"]=> string(2) "B2" ["quote2"]=> string(26) "Enter your meal preference" ["education2"]=> string(7) "person2" ["edu2"]=> string(5) "weld2" ["jsonval"]=> string(0) "" }
```

I guess I should mention it was encoded as a serialized object from the form page and then encoded and sent over...Don't know if that will make a difference.

Anyway, I dutifully check the PHP manual, and everything, as always, looks simple enough to implement.  And then, of course, I try it just the way they tell me and I miss something that's probably obvious to everyone here but me.  This bit of code, returns nothing except my text that I'm echoing:

```
<?php
$json = $_GET['jsonval'];
$obj = var_dump(json_decode($json));

echo "<br><br>ELEMENT PLEASE!" . $obj;
print $obj->{"Fname"}; // 12345

?>
```

I mean, all I want is to see the values of my individual key/values and print them out.  What have I done wrong here?

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: So I tried the answer below and no joy.  

$obj = var_dump(json_decode($json));
echo "<br>NAME:::      ";
print $obj->Fname;

Produces nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line is completely wrong:

```
$obj = var_dump(json_decode($json));
```

`var_dump()` returns nothing

You need:

```
$obj = json_decode($json);
```

Turn `display_errors` `on` in your php.ini and set up `ERROR_REPORTING = E_ALL`. And continue developing with such settings.

Comment: That worked!  Sorry to trot such painfully obvious stuff out into these forums, but I do learn each and everytime I post here.

Answer (score 0):

You put this:
`print $obj->{"Fname"}; // 12345`

It should be
`print $obj->Fname; // 12345`

Comment: Well, if it is correct the way you have it above then A) why the #!$@ is the PHP manual saying it should be written another way (costing this n00b a few hours of headbanging) and B) it, naturally, still won't work for me.  But that's absolutely no surprise.

Comment: The second format is preferred because it's less typing and looks better. However, in some cases valid JSON will give you invalid PHP properties. e.g., `$a->foo-bar` is not equivalent to `$a->{'foo-bar'}`. (The first is subtraction: `$a->foo - bar`.) If you prefer to work with arrays or want to ignore the problem altogether, you can pass `true` as the second parameter to `json_decode`.

Comment: Good explanation.  I really was clueless as to why the examples had true in there.  I swear, I should get a domain name like itshouldbesimple.com and use it to explain the stuff you guys know and I don't get until it's finally explained to me and THEN it seems obvious.  Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not calling out data from the object incorrectly.

Needs to be something like:

```
$data = (json_decode(urldecode('{%22Fname%22:+%22kjhjhkjhk%22,+%22Lname%22:+%22ghghfhg%22,+%22conf[]%22:+[%22ConfB%22,+%22ConfA2%22],+%22quote%22:+%22meat%22,+%22education%22:+%22person%22,+%22edu%22:+%22welding%22,+%22Fname2%22:+%22%22,+%22Lname2%22:+%22%22,+%22gender%22:+%22B2%22,+%22quote2%22:+%22Enter+your+meal+preference%22,+%22education2%22:+%22person2%22,+%22edu2%22:+%22weld2%22,+%22jsonval%22:+%22%22}')));
echo $data->Fname;
```